What does "Camping on my trail!" mean?
A grizzled prospector discovers a large gold vein, "Mr. Pocket", in
a mountain valley. A young man shoots him in the back,
but the prospector feigns death. The prospector then
overpowers the young man and shoots him dead.

Prospector: You measly skunk! Camping on my trail!
Letting me do all the work!
And shooting me in the back!

What does "Camping on my trail!" mean?

The phrase did  come to have a figurative meaning in the late 19th century (i.e. "pestering me") but here it is used literally.

You should name the source. Please edit your answer and include the name of the movie.

It's not a common or standard expression.  So you have to work it out from the meaning of the words.
The prospector is unhappy because he accuses the young man of "letting me do the work". So it seems the young man is trying to follow the prospector in the hope that by doing so, the prospector will lead him to the secret gold site.
So "camping" is literal:  "setting up a tent"  and "my trail" is the trail that the prospector makes though the outback. The young man is following the prospector by following the trail that the prospector makes, in order to discover the prospector's gold vein, with the intent to murder the prospector and steal the gold.
